# Unable to resolve DNS queries

Tags: 15.10, dns

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 host and have a 15.10 server running in virtualbox.  This is all a fresh install that I completed 3 days ago.

When I logged in last night to run "apt-get update", nothing resolved.

I'm attempting to use my router as the DNS server server.  That's how I have the rest of my LAN setup.  I can resolve successfully from the host, but I cannot resolve anything from the guest.

```
 source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

 # The loopback network interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 # The primary network interface
 auto enp0s3
 iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.1.4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-namesevers 192.168.1.1
```

I can ping my router.  If I change the dns-nameservers to 8.8.8.8 and restart networking, I still can't resolve google.com.  There's something on the box that's preventing DNS queries from resolving and I'm not sure what could cause it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any firewall/iptable rules? Just in case? Can you tell us result of "telnet 192.168.1.1 53" from your guest system and also from your supervisor system? Just for a starter.

Comment: Also - are you absolutely sure, that your supervisor system is also using 192.168.1.1 as DNS? Is DNS working fine on that IP, for sure?

Comment: I personally did not setup any firewall/iptable rules.  In fact, I have to lookup how to check that to confirm.  I wouldn't even know how to enter them to begin with.

When I telnet to the router it says it's connected.  I can't interact with it at all, it just goes to the next line when I send a command.  Same from host system as well.

Yes, the host is using 192.168.1.1 as DNS.  When I do a dig though, it's querying itself (127.0.0.1)

Comment: 'linenoise@servermoo:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for linenoise:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
linenoise@servermoo:~$'

(all blank, that did not copy gracefully at all and I can't get the 'code' tag to work here)

Comment: Well - to be honest, if you say telnet to port 53 works from both host/hypervisor and guest - maybe there's something in the configuration that makes dns not respond to the guest with the proper answer. I'm afraid that I can be only guessing here. You have to check things carefully on your system.

Comment: Well - maybe try to post results of something like that: "dig @192.168.1.1 google.com" (or whatever else address) from both servers, to see the feedback from your DNS. Run it on both systems to compare output - maybe this will shed some light on the issue.

Comment: my resolv.conf is blank.  I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and rebooted, but it's still blank.  This is where I'm currently at.

Answer (score 0):

the same thing going on here I think it is something related to DNSMASQ  some times dns resolution never works ,some times it works slowly taking for each name about 3 seconds to resolv ,and sometimes it runs really fast as it should be . I'm running ubuntu 15.10 and yes I tried to change dns servers to my ISP,Goolge,and opendns nothing seems to be stable

UPDATE: I think I found the solution

SOLUTION

The problem seems to be related to the conflicting dnsmasq and resolvconf packages. Until 12.10, dnsmasq was used. From 13.04 onwards, Ubuntu seemed to switch to a dnsmasq/resolvconf hybrid, where you have installed the packages dnsmasq-base and resolvconf, but not dnsmasq itself.

I can't say if it's a bug in the upgrade scripts for 13.04 or something else, because when upgrading (as in fresh installs) resolvconf is installed, dnsmasq-base is upgraded and dnsmasq is (correctly) uninstalled.

The catch is, the upgrade script fails to comment out the dns=dnsmasq line in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. So, even though the dnsmasq daemon is not present anymore on the system, /etc/resolv.conf still expects it to be.

SO to fix the problem edit this file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf  and  comment this line : #dns=dnsmasq

hope this helps some one